# How do I get the List Filters similar to the ones in admin console in my list views?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filters, django-admin-filters

I am writing my first django app and in one of my ListView there will be hundreds of records. I want the user to be able to filter the result. The filter widget in the admin console looks intuitive for any kind of user. But the problem is, I am not sure how I can get them in my List Views.

I have briefly looked into the django-filters. But, I am not sure if it can help me achieve similar functionalities.

Comment: What type of filter do you require exactly?

Comment: Some of my columns holds string data, and some hold dates. I would like to provide a means to filter them. The date filter in admin console has options like:today, last 7 days, past month etc. I wanted those in my listview.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like this:

in Template of the list view:

```
<form path="{% url 'your_list_view' %}" method="GET">
    <label for="search">Search: </label>
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Now use this in ListView:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class YourListView(ListView):
   search_fields = ['name', 'something_else']
   ...
   def get_querset(self, *args, **kwargs):
       queryset = super(YourListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
       search = request.GET.get('search')
       if search:
          query = list()
          for f in self.search_fields:
              query.append(Q(**{f: search}))
          return queryset.filter(*query)
       return queryset
```